# How to give TypeORM Datasource from middleware to Nestjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, middleware

I have a middleware that create a connection from TypeORM to the database wanted, at each request to the api.

I would like to link the created Datasource connexion to Nestjs and use the Datasource from the Nestjs injections like :

```
@InjectDatasource()
```

The only things I could have done was to pass the TypeORM Datasource has a part of request so the controllers could use it.

Is there a way to do it from the Nestjs injection directly ? It would be better and easier for the developpers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you creating a connection in the middleware? Does the connection need to change per request?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Yes, the connection need to change per request. I will receive from the http header the instance of database aimed and connect to it before processing the request.

Comment: So why not REQUEST scope the TypeORM module configuration using `forRootAsync` and an `inject: [REQUEST]`? That way, `@InjectConnection()` and the `@InjectRepository()`s are always pointed at the right database